# Edit and update gridview rows on mouse click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to edit and update gridview rows on mouse click event. If the user clicks on a row it should become editable and when he again clicks on the same row it should become uneditable and the changes should be saved.

my gridview looks like:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdexcelsheet" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                onpageindexchanging="grdexcelsheet_PageIndexChanging" 
                Width = "100%" Height = "100%" Font-Size="Small">
                <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast"  FirstPageText="First" 
                     LastPageText="Last"  NextPageText="Next" PreviousPageText="Prev" PageButtonCount="5" />
                <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SrNo" HeaderText="SrNo" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CustomerFieldName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerFieldName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerFieldName") %>'>
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyFieldName" HeaderText="CompanyFieldName" ReadOnly="true" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Usage" HeaderText="Usage" ReadOnly="true" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can use [AJAX Control Toolkit Modal Popup Extender](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Edit-Update-Records-in-GridView-using-Modal-Popup-in-ASP.Net.aspx)   for updating your grid. Also, you can make use Update Panel from the same toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use third party controls...please use this which will be very to use

http://obout.com/grid/grid_commands.aspx...